# Want to change chartjs bar width and on click of bar stroke values from another div should get change

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I am using `chartjs` script to display a bar chart. Displayed the views and visitors bars and overlapped it on one another. Now I want to reduce the width of the resultant bar and on the clickEvent of the bar stroke should another div get changed which is having proper values from a database. I have gone through all queries related with `chartjs` on StackOverflow, but failed to implement it.

This is what I have tried:

```
<canvas id="barChart" style="height:5px; width:30px;"  ></canvas>
script=>

/* javascript to show bar chart for weekly analysis */

    $(function () {
    var areaChartData = {
    labels  : ['Nov-15', 'Nov-22', 'Nov-29', 'Dec-06','Dec-13', 'Dec-19']
    datasets: [
    {
    label             : 'Total View Count',
    fillColor           : '#0087be',
    strokeColor         : '#0087be',
    pointColor          : '#0087be',
    pointStrokeColor    : '#0087be',
    pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
    pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
    barPercentage         : 0.5,

    data                : [1, 3, 2,2, 7,2,]
    },
    {
    label               : 'Total Visitors Count',
    fillColor           : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
    strokeColor          :'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
    pointColor          : '#3b8bba',
    pointStrokeColor    : 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
    pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
    pointHighlightStroke  : 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
    barPercentage     : 0.5,

     data                : [1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2]
     },
     ],
     }

     var barChartCanvas  = $('#barChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
     var barChart   = new Chart(barChartCanvas)
     var barChartData                     = areaChartData
     barChartData.datasets[1].fillColor   = '#004069'
     barChartData.datasets[1].strokeColor = '#004069'
     barChartData.datasets[1].pointColor  = '#004069'

     var barChartOptions  = {

    options: {
     scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        barPercentage: 1,
    categoryPercentage: 0.5 / 10 * barChartData.datasets[0].data.length }],
     yAxes: [{
         ticks: {
                 beginAtZero:true
                }
         }],
         }
        },

    //Boolean - Whether the scale should start at 
   zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value

     barStrokeWidth          : 2,
    barValueSpacing         : 15,
    barDatasetSpacing       : -175,
    datasetStroke           : true,
    barDatasetWidth       : -10,
    dataPointMaxWidth       : 20,
    responsive              : true,
    maintainAspectRatio     : true,

     }

     barChartOptions.datasetFill = false;

    barChart.Bar(barChartData, barChartOptions)

    });

            [bar image shown in picture want to reduce bar stroke width. Two 
             bars are  having different blue color shed][1]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: code edited sir..kindly guide me iff possible.

Comment: Now tell us what *exactly* your problem is.

Comment: I have shown two bars. one for views and another for visitors. these two bars are overlapped using  barDatasetSpacing       : -175, now this resultant bar width is large and I want to show in small width of this bar .. what should i do now?

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to explain to me. Do you mean that if they overlap, so the `resultantBar` is too big, you want to reduce the width of `resultantBar` until they dont overlap?

Comment: they are now in overlapped position and i want to reduce width of bar stroke

Comment: There you go: [solution](https://www.google.de/search?source=hp&ei=slI6WoisIoWdkwWMk5XgCA&q=chartjs+reduce+width+of+bar&oq=chartjs+reduce+width+of+bar&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1.756.18374.0.18746.27.27.0.0.0.0.95.1392.27.27.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.27.1388...0j0i131k1j0i10k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1j0i8i13i10i30k1.0.GLUVXFUpIRs).

Comment: trying for this https://github.com/ejancorp/chartjs-bar-maxwidth/blob/master/chartjs.custombarchart.js

Comment: I don't have time to do **your** work. Put some effort in it, make some research and try again, a few times though. That's how programming works and *if* you are really stuck afterwards, then come back to us and ask for some help. And this is how Stack Overflow works. :-)

Comment: thanks for your time sir, i changed my script and now it works . I reffered https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3946